# Why is getState() not a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, redux

I'm trying to create a simple Cart using Redux, but removeFromCart() function throws an error.

I have created a `cartActions.js` file with two dispatch functions, `addToCart()` function that works as it should  and  `removeFromCart()`  function that returns `TypeError: getState is not a function`.

How can I fix this problem ?

This is the `cartActions.js` file:

```
import { ADD_TO_CART, REMOVE_FROM_CART } from "../types";

export const addToCart = (product) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const cartItems = getState().cart.cartItems.slice();
  let alreadyExists = false;
  cartItems.forEach((x) => {
    if (x._id === product._id) {
      alreadyExists = true;
      x.count++;
    }
  });
  if (!alreadyExists) {
    cartItems.push({ ...product, count: 1 });
  }
  dispatch({
    type: ADD_TO_CART,
    payload: { cartItems },
  });
  localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(cartItems));
  console.log(cartItems)
};


export const removeFromCart = (product) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const cartItems = getState().cart.cartItems.slice()
    .filter((x) => x._id !== product._id);
  dispatch({
  type: REMOVE_FROM_CART, 
  payload: { cartItems },
  });
  localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(cartItems));
};
```

This is the error that I get:

```
    24 | 
  25 | export const removeFromCart = (product) => (dispatch, getState) => {
> 26 |   const cartItems = getState().cart.cartItems.slice()
  27 |     .filter((x) => x._id !== product._id);
  28 |   dispatch({
  29 |         type: REMOVE_FROM_CART,
```

The error occurs when the cart component is supposed to render.

I have a function `openCart()` that alternate between rendering the "Shop" and "Cart" when I press the button the error occurs

This is the `openCart()` function:

```js
openCart = () => {
        this.setState({openCartStatus:!this.state.openCartStatus});
    } // the function starts  with  openCartStatus as false
```

The `cart.js` file is long but I think it’s  necessary to include  it for reference.
I used react hooks for `cart.js`.

this is the `cart.js`:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import './cart.css'
import { useIntersection } from 'react-use';

import formatCurrency from '../../../util'
import { Fade } from "react-awesome-reveal";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { removeFromCart } from '../../../actions/cartActions';

 function Cart (props) {
          
        const sectionRef = useRef(null);

        const intersection = useIntersection(sectionRef, {
            root: null,
            rootMargin: "80%",
            threshold: 0.8,
        });
  
        const { cartItems } = props;
        return (
            <div className="container" >
                <div className="cart_container" ref={sectionRef}>
                 <div className="cart_icon_container">
                     <div  className={intersection && intersection.intersectionRatio < 0.5 ? "cart_Icon" : "cart_Icon_Btn"} onClick={() => {
                    props.openCart();
                    }}>
                        <img alt='cart-icon' src='./Images/icons8-shopping-bag-32.png' ></img>
                 </div> 
              </div> 
               

                {cartItems.length === 0 ? (
                 <div className="cart cart_header"> 
                Cart Is Empty
                </div>
                    ) : (
                <div className="cart cart_header">
                     You Have {cartItems.length} Itames In The Cart{""}
                </div>
                )}
                <div> 
                    <div className="cart">
                        <Fade direction="up" triggerOnce cascade duration="750">
                        <ul className="cart_items">
                            {cartItems.map((item , index ) => (
                                <li key={index}>
                                    <div className="cart_image">
                                        <img src={item.image} alt={item.name}></img>
                                    </div> 
                <div className="ShopItem_details_discription">
                    <div className="productInfo_Container">
                            <div> LOGO </div>
                            <div className="productInfo">
                            <h2>{item.name}</h2>
                                <p>{item.info}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div >
                                <p> Phone Number</p>
                                <div className="flourType_Container" >
                                    {item.flourType.map((x)=>(  
                                    <div>{" "}{x}</div>
                                    ))}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            
                        </div>
                                    <div className="cart_mengment">
                                        {formatCurrency(item.price)}
                                        <div className="btn_containar">
                                            <button onClick={() => props.addAmount(item)} className  = "Btn" > + </button>
                                            <div className = "ItemCounte"> {item.count}</div>
                                            <button onClick={() => props.subAmount(item, index)} className  = "Btn" > - </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <button className="cart_item_remove" onClick={() => props.removeFromCart(index)}>
                                            Remove
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            ))}

                        </ul>
                        </Fade>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {cartItems.length !== 0 && (
             <div className="cart">
                    <div className="total">
                        <div >
                            TOTAL{"   "}
                            {formatCurrency(
                                cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + c.price * c.count, 0)
                            )}
                        </div>
                        <button className="proceed_Btn" onClick={() => {
                            props.showCheckout();
                            }}> 
                            Proceed
                        </button>
                 </div> 
             </div>
             )} 
            </div>
        </div>
            
        )
    }

    export default connect((state) => ({
        cartItems: state.cart.cartItems,
        }),
        removeFromCart
    )(Cart);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass object as mapDispatchToProps in connect method instead of just removeFromCard.

```
export default connect((state) => ({
   cartItems: state.cart.cartItems,
}),
{ removeFromCart }
)(Cart);
```

Comment: ok thanx so much, I checked the cod and it worked, both  answers  worked , but the remove button and function did not remove the cart item is something wrong withe the function it’s self ?

Comment: issue with removeCart function is that you are expecting product but you are passing index so that could be issue. you should pass item instead of index.

Comment: ok nice   I converted the "index" to "item" ( item - is the key word for individual  product ), and it worked  YEY

Answer (score 1):

Read: https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch

Your case scenario is essentially the first example. You don't *need* to pass your `removeFromCart` function to the component as it's already available due to your import.

If you remove the 2nd argument from `connect`, Redux's `dispatch` function is passed as a prop. So you'd need to change

```
export default connect((state) => ({
    cartItems: state.cart.cartItems,
}),
    removeFromCart
)(Cart);
```

to

```
export default connect((state) => ({
    cartItems: state.cart.cartItems,
}))(Cart);
```

and

```
<button className="cart_item_remove" onClick={() => props.removeFromCart(index)}>Remove</button>
```

to

```
<button className="cart_item_remove" onClick={() => props.dispatch(removeFromCart(index))}>Remove</button>
```

and it should work as expected (at least the getState function should work).

Tip: Look at Redux lifecycle implementations, Redux is incredibly complex at first glance but after you simplify the implementation with standards...it's really easy. I'd look at `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps` in the link above.

Example

Component.js

```
export function Component({ hello, setHello }) {

    return <>
        <p>{hello}</p>
        <button onClick={() => setHello('Bye')}>
    </>
}
```

container.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Component } from './Component.js';
import { setHello } from './action.js';

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {

    return {
        hello: state.hello
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {

    return {
        setHello: (input) => {

            dispatch(setHello(input));
        }
    }
}

connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component);
```

Comment: the Solution worked  both yours  and  the answer  above thanx so much, but i see now that the remove function  it’s  self doesn’t work, can you teach me what  went wrong?

Comment: No worries, do you have a reducer setup to mutate the state?

Comment: i can edit in the cartReducer, I don’t think I have set up to mutate the state